# Connect to LocalDB with new ODBC Driver for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, localdb

UPDATE: Thanks to Dan Guzman, the problem has been solved.
I'd made a mistake and used the old legacy `Driver={SQL Server};` assuming it is the new driver. Instead, I should have used `Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}` which is the actual new ODBC driver.
I can connect to **(Localdb)\v11.0** with the new driver.

---

**TL;TR**: Why I can not connect to **(Localdb)\v11.0** using the new `Driver={SQL Server};` in connection string, but I can connet if I switch the driver to the old `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};` ?

The remaining connection string parameters I use are (if used in C++ code, backslash escaped):

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;
```

I'm trying to access SQL Server via ODBC and calling `SQLDriverConnect` with DSN-less connection string. If I switch the driver to **SQL Server Native Client 11.0**, then I suddenly can connect.

I have also tested generating FILEDSN using `%systemdrive%\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` and I observed exactly the same issue.

The only local database I can connect with the new `Driver={SQL Server}` is `Server=DEVBOX\SQLEXPRESS` (if used in C++ code, backslash escaped, of course).

I couldn't find any confirmation that the new ODBC Driver for SQL Server does not support LocalDB.

It is only indicated in the FAQ of [ODBC Driver for SQL Server for Linux](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451.aspx)

> Which features of SQL Server 2012 does this version of the driver
>   support?
>       The ODBC driver on Linux supports all server features in SQL Server 2012 except LocalDB.

How can I connect to LocalDB with the new ODBC driver on Windows?

UPDATE:
I'm using Windows 10 Pro + VS2015.
I can connect to both, `(localdb)\v11.0` and `DEVBOX\SQLEXPRESS` with SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (CTP).
(The same question has been asked on MSDN Forums, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8fc36948-3792-4d1d-93df-91186d81a784/connecting-to-localdb-with-new-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).)

Comment: is SQL-Native-Client installed?

Comment: @CPMunich I believe the fact I see it listed in odbcad32.exe indicates it is installed. BTW, I have added OS env info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ODBC driver `SQL Server` is the legacy SQL Server ODBC driver that ships with Windows for backwards compatibility.  The latest SQL Server ODBC driver is `ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server`.  I believe this ODBC driver is installed with SQL Server 2016 CTP.  The released version is available as a [separate download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434).

Comment: My mistake, indeed. I found MSDN page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730315.aspx) that confirms: The driver name that you specify in a connection string is ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.

Comment: Just an update: the latest ODBC Driver for SQL Server is now 13. You can download it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server). I tried to connect to local db instance in RODBC. It failed using the legacy {SQL Server} driver and succeeded with {ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} .